# Crystal Dynamic Parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My report has three dynamic multi value parameters. The problem is when I publish the report to the repository, the available values do not show up. Its all blank. I tried mapping the parameter values to LOVs created in Business Views, but that is also not working somehow. Any idea what i might be doing wrong or need to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you schedule your list of values in Business View Manager?  Right click on the LOV then select schedule list of values - either run now or schedule.